# Call a component method from HTML in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

Is it possible to call a component method from HTML, or should I create another component to handle formatting?

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div class="title">{{ item.Title }}</div>
  <p>
    callComponentMethodHere({{item}})
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
{{callComponentMethodHere(item)}}
```

but you should avoid that because the method will be called every time change detection runs. It's better to call the method in code (for example in the `constructor()`, `ngOnInit()`, or an event handler, assign the result to a property and from the view bind to that property instead.

Calling event handlers is fine of course:

```
<button (click)="callComponentMethodHere(item)">click me</button>
```