# Angular2 function call from html element with no load event (or similiar)

Tags: html, angular

I am new to Angular and have run into a problem that seems to have a javascript work around but they aren't very elegant.

I have a model with an array property. I ngfor the list property to build some html selection options. This is all working nicely. The problem comes when I am trying to set default value...the html elements don't have a load event.

I tried numerous html elements and they don't appear to have a load event either but I certainly could be doing it wrong.

I have seen a solution to put javascript tag right after the html and I could do that but I was really looking for a more elegant way in Angular.

I saw this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066490/call-a-component-method-from-html-in-angular2) and thought that was my answer but there is a warning given that I agree with and thus it doesn't appear to be a good solution.
Regardless I tried it just to see if it would work and I got:

Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '{{loadDefaults()}}' is not a valid attribute name

```
<span {{loadDefaults()}} ></span>
```

**So how can I fire an AS2 function in the component to load the default values?**

HTML (btw this is NOT a full page load so there is no body tag):

```
<tr>
   <td *ngFor="let loc of locOptions;">
      <span>{{loc.text}}</span>
      <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" [value]="loc.value" (change)="onSelectionChange(loc.value)">
  </td>
</tr>
```

---

Edit

I thought perhaps mistakenly that ngoninit would fire too soon...before the html elements are rendered.

So perhaps what is being suggested is that I add a boolean is default to the model and bind THAT as the element is rendered.

Comment: What do you mean by AS2 ? ActionScript ?

Comment: So you just want to initialize `locOptions` with default values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ngOnInit` to init you data, and call retrieve your data from your component :

```
defaults : any;

ngOnInit { 
  this.defaults = loadDefaults();
}

loadDefaults() {
  //get data
}
```

HTML :

```
<span>{{defaults}}</span>
```

Comment: Just wanted to add one thing. Component should implement `OnInit` interface like `class MyComponent implements OnInit { }`.

Comment: I should have mentioned this in the OP...see my edits.

Comment: `ngOnInit` is called (only once) after the html elements are rendered : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#hooks-purpose-timing

Answer (score 3):

In your ngonit function set this.locOptions to your default values. The value can be changed later on in any function and the change will be reflected in the view. Hope this helps you.